# Countdown timer for idle session using JS error when counter

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a countdown timer when idle session is on. Sometimes the countdown makes count twice, I'm not able to identify why you're counting twice.

```js
resetTimer = () => {
  clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  startClockToEndSession();
}

var timeoutInMilisecondsToStartCount = 2580000;
var timeoutId;

startClockToEndSession = () => {
  timeoutId = setTimeout(countDownDisplay, timeoutInMilisecondsToStartCount);
}

displayTimeoutSession = () => {
  window.location.href = abp.appPath + 'Account/LogoutSessionExpired';
}

checkIdle = () => {
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", resetTimer, false);
  document.addEventListener("mousedown", resetTimer, false);
  document.addEventListener("keypress", resetTimer, false);
  document.addEventListener("touchmove", resetTimer, false);
  clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  setTimeout(startClockToEndSession, timeoutInMilisecondsToStartCount);
}

countDownDisplay = () => {

  var counter = 60;
  var interval = setInterval(() => {
    counter--;

    if (counter > 0) {
      $('#countDownSession').text("Sua sessão expira em " + counter + " segundo(s)");
      $(document).on('mousemove', () => {
        counter = -1;
      });
      $(document).on('mousedown', () => {
        counter = -1;
      });
      $(document).on('keypress', () => {
        counter = -1;
      });
      $(document).on('touchmove', () => {
        counter = -1;
      });
    } else if (counter === 0) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      $('#countDownSession').text("Sessão expirada");
      displayTimeoutSession();
      resetTimer;
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
      $('#countDownSession').text('');
      resetTimer;
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

The countDownDisplay function count twice, and cause some confusion. Where is my mistake in this function?

Comment: I'm not sure but notice that you bind multiple `mousemove`, `mousedown` etc. events to the document. Why multiple? Because you do this inside the interval callback which fires again and again.

Comment: @MoshFeu in this case it only a validation with users interact with mouse events, I'm try to cover all situation with mouse events

Comment: I meant that the same events bound multiple times. Although it's not optimal, it not causes the issue you describe. Try to set a breakpoint inside `countDownDisplay` and track who is ht step before who call it. Maybe there is other code who call it. I don't see a case in the code you posted..

Comment: @MoshFeu I understand, thanks for the tips, I will try to do this check and see where else is causing this.